# how copy constructor evoked during type conversion from class type to class type

Tags: c++

Suppose I have to do type conversion (from object of one class to object of another class )
Then I know that it can be done in two ways

1- by making constructor at the destination side
2- by using conversion function (operator)

So, I want to know that how the constructor is called as constructor is called only when a object is created and in our situation there is no creation of object as my object is already created...

Ex:
Suppose two classes test and base,
then

```
void main
     test ob1
     base ob2
(ob1=ob2)   how this statement calls constructor?
```

I am attaching the link to my program code..
http://codepad.org/1IK4R3Q8

Comment: It would be better if you posted a compilable example which reproduces your problem. The code you have posted above is not valid C++.

Comment: Now I have attached my program...

Comment: this is the "Magic" of C++, and if you like and accept this sort of magic, you may like the language, if you let the complicated semantics bother you (like I do) then it may the a language that you like less than others... I personally don't think that C++ should be taught in into CS classes because there is so much unneeded complexity...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're seeing is implicit *converting construction*. The compiler is invoking the copy constructor of class `con` which takes an object of type `test` as an argument.

The compiler finds no compatible assignment operator, so it sees if it can convert the `ob1` object some other way.

It finds that the `con` class has a compatible copy constructor, so it invokes it *implicitly* to allow the assignment to take place.

See reference [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor):

> Implicitly-declared and user-defined non-explicit copy constructors
>   and move constructors are converting constructors.

You can avoid this behavior by using the keyword `explicit` before the copy constructor declaration in `con`. This will prevent the compiler from invoking it implictly.

Comment: @user5084928: No problem - consider marking as accepted if you're happy with the explanation!

Comment: Your phrase "constructor of `ob1`" is totally false.  In the quoted code `ob1` is not being constructed in any sense, not a "converting" constructor nor any other kind.  `ob1` is being assigned to and only that.  Everything else happens on the right hand side of that assignment.

Comment: @JSF: you're completely right, I had a fusion of two earlier answers, and the sense was lost in the merge. I've updated the answer now. Apologies.

Comment: @user5084928: I believe you need to click the big tick next to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If that statement calls a constructor then it will also call the destructor.  The main operation you showed was `operator=` in which `ob1` is assigned **something**.

That **something** might be a temporary of type `test` which might be created in one of the two ways you described, in which case after the `operator=` the destructor is called.  But the conversion possibility you described might instead return a `test&` or `test const&` and the `operator=` might take that, so no constructor nor destructor required.

You might also be wrong about any conversion being needed.  It could be that `test::operator=` has an overload to take the provided `base&` directly without first having it converted.